# Is there any way to merge several TURN servers?

Tags: webrtc, turn

For example, I have set up TURN server and created webrtc-based mesh-network. Then when load on my TURN server significantly increases as the number of clients increases, I want to add another TURN server. How to merge their knowledge about clients? I mean can old TURN server tell the newest TURN server which clients ale already in its database?

It is the problem because, as I understand, with 2 TURN servers it could be situations in which the same client have two different representations in terms of TURN. So it may bring in indetermination in network.

I am reading currently RFC 5766 documentation. But I still have not found out the answer.

Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is absolutely no requirement that clients reside on the same TURN server. You can just send new clients to the new TURN server and they will be able to connect to other clients just fine. DNS-based round-robin load balancing usually works quite well.

Comment: So I am a client `A` and I was connected to TURN server `B` for like 1year. Now server `Y` appears and client `X` is connected to it. Can `A` talk to `X` without connecting directly to `Y` or what would be needed for `A` to talk to `X`?

Comment: Yes. `A`  creates an allocation on turn server `B` which is essentially a port. It can use that port to send data anywhere, including the port that client `X` created on server `Ỳ`.

Comment: Yet how will ‘A’ get any idea of ‘X’ existence in the first place while connected only to ‘B’?

Comment: candidate exchange is the job of the signaling server, not the stun/turn server.